# How to solve "no rule to make target 'install'" while installing ffnvcodec (Windows)

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, makefile, precompiled-headers, make-install

I tried to install ffnvcodec for ffmpeg on windows and when I try to install it I get:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.". The command is: "make install PREFIX=/usr

and:

1. Since I'm still learning, I get that `PREFIX=/usr` is the directory where I want my program to be installed (correct me if I'm wrong), but I don't know how to specify the location (if you could give me an example it'd be great).
2. On Nvidia site it says to copy all headers files in a specific directory, which I did, but it gives me this error. I'm new to this, so I don't know what to do and I can't find any solution to this problem.

Comment: Supposing that the build instructions direct you to run the `make install` command you present, my best guess would be that you are running it from a different directory than the one in which you built the program.

Comment: Also, if `PREFIX=/usr` does anything in that command, that would be specific to the makefile(s) involved.  It has  no particular significance to `make` itself.

Comment: Ahhhhh okay I get it, thank you so much for the answer. Though I feel I'll be back on this site to ask more questions ahah.